# How to bring the footer down

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using an iframe in master page. I have two master pages. once the user enters, 2nd master page applies. So the second master page has iframe, I want the footer appear benith the iframe.

css for iframe :

```
iframe 
 { position:fixed; height: 100%; display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
```

The html is:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH10/" style="width:100%; height:100%; bottom="100%; frameborder="0";
                allowfullscreen">
   </iframe> 
</div>
```

My footer:

```
 <div>
     <br/><br/>
     <center style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial">
          Please contact Human Resources with any additional questions or concerns via email a <br/>
      </center>
 </div>
```

Problem is : the footer is coming on the content. Not at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your iframe have a `fixed position` then the footer is going to the top of the page.

`position:fixed` extracts the element and leaves the space to be filled by the other elements.

Two solutions:

**One** If you can, better set your iframe with `position:relative`

**Two** Set a `margin-top` to your footer equal to the `height` of your iframe.